# Install custom extension to visual studio for mac

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-mac

I just wrote my first extension for visual studio for mac. It works wonderfully when I run it, so naturally I would like to install it to my IDE.
This however is my problem. I don't know how..
I googled it but I can't seem to find any clear explanation on how to install my own extension or on how to publish it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `App Menu` / `Extensions` / `Install from file` and consult the MonoDevelop docs for publishing : http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/publishing-an-addin/

Comment: Yes, I saw the install from file button, but when I browsed my directory there were no valid files. Which file should it be?

Comment: You are looking for the `.mpack` file (it is a zip file that contains the addin xml and addin files/resources/...), so if you do not know what that is, I assume that you have not actually create one then. The AddinMaker provides MSBuild targets to create / install / test these addins:  https://github.com/mhutch/MonoDevelop.AddinMaker/wiki/Build-System#targets

Comment: You can build them form the cmd-line: `msbuild SomeExtProject.csproj /target:PackageAddin` Or you can create a new build configuration in the `.csproj` and set the target property in that configuration

Comment: https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit/blob/7.0/dist.package.local.sh Another alternative is to use `vstool.exe` directly.

Comment: Thanks guys. The cmd-line solution worked perfectly

Comment: @Max Helskens, If this issue has been resolved, you could share your solution as an answer, so you could mark it and it could help other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments above:

- Install from file: msbuild SomeExtProject.csproj /target:PackageAddin
- Publish: read [this article](http://monodevelop.com/developers/articles/publishing-an-addin)